# Using Custom Comparer With Linq IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am trying to use a custom comparer on a query generated using Linq. I've seen many articles saying that you cannot do that, but when I look at the signatures for the Distinct extension method I see this: (this IQueryable source, IEqualityComparer comparer)..

Why is there a constructor that accepts a custom comparer if it cannot be converted to sql through Linq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that linq is more than just linq to sql, linq to entities or anything else.

When using queryable you always have a provider. There is no requirement for the provider to support everything that linq can do. This is one such example.

The reason it is there is because a different provider might choose to support a different set of functionality such as the custom comparer.

In general I believe that everything that can be done to an `IEnumerable` through LINQ can be done to an `IQueryable`.

I will agree that this one is probably going to be one of the harder things to translate to whatever your provider links to but the symmetry between `Enumerable` and `Queryable` and the fact somebody *might* is I suspect the reason they exist.